# How to run custom SQL queries in Moodle?

Tags: sql, moodle

I found the predefined query functions in Moodle are not very handy when the query is getting complex. Most predefined functions can be found here: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API

I am wondering if there is a function in Moodle that allows me to run any custom SQL queries so that I can do whatever I need to the Moodle DB (i.e. like using php query() function to run custom queries).

One example would be, I was trying to get last row from the table *'trigger_message'*, I know in php I can do

```
$sql=("
      SELECT Trigger_id 
      FROM trigger_message 
      ORDER BY trigger_Id 
      DESC limit 1
     ");

$id = $DB->query($sql);
```

But in moodle I have no clue how to do it, could anybody advise please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every one of the Moodle DB functions has an _sql variant that accepts SQL + params - see the docs here: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API

So, from your example, you will probably want something like:

```
$id = $DB->get_field_sql("SELECT MAX(trigger_id) FROM {trigger_message}");
```

(which will sort out the correct prefix for the trigger_message table - usually mdl_trigger_message).

However, for the example you have given, you probably want to write:

```
$id = $DB->get_field('trigger_message', 'MAX(trigger_id)');
```

Comment: Thank you fro your answer Davo, but is there a function that allows me to run any quires like query() in php?

Comment: I think I already answered that - $DB->get_field_sql() will do exactly what the query function will be doing.

Comment: And if that doesn't do what you want, then the link I gave also lists get_records_sql, get_record_sql, get_fieldset_sql and all of the recordset variants. One of those will definitely do what you want.